# How to nest routing with AppMainComponent and multiple featured modules

Tags: angular

Recently I implemented a theme template into my project which has an AppMainComponent, which contains all shared components frame like menu, topbar, footbar etc. After implementing it I found I can't see these shared components, only my feature modules templates can be rendered.I tried to debug and I found the Oninit method of AppMainComponent is never called, it seemed this component is not loaded, but it is in AppModule.ts for sure.
My AppRoutingModule is like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: AppMainComponent,
        children: [
            {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
        ]
    },
    {path: 'error', component: AppErrorComponent},
    {path: 'access', component: AppAccessdeniedComponent},
    {path: 'notfound', component: AppNotfoundComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: AppLoginComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound'},
]
```

And my featured module is like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children:[
      {path:'Workbench',component:WorkbenchComponent},  
      {path:'',redirectTo:'Workbench',pathMatch:'full'},
    ]
  }
];
```

the template of AppMainComponent is like:

```
<div class="layout-wrapper">

    <app-topbar></app-topbar>

    <app-rightpanel></app-rightpanel>

    <div class="menu-wrapper" (click)="onMenuClick($event)">
        <div class="layout-menu-container">
            <app-menu></app-menu>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="layout-main">

        <div class="layout-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>

        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you please share the code?
Could there be a problem with the AuthGuard?

Comment: Thank for your attention, what else code are you concerning? I checked the guard, login and jwt, they are ok. But AppMainComponent is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ron evans said the quetion is not clear but here are some paths that you can follow :

1. check if the shared components are in the declation array ( in appMain.module) if not import theme.
2. the feature module should be lazy loading so AppRoutingModule should be something like this :

   {path: '[feature path name]',loadChildren : ([feature module path])=>m.featureModule}

otherwise, if you don't want lazy loading you can import fearture module in AppMain.module.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but all the shared modules are decleared in appModule. The problem is that the appMainComponent never worked. And what code else should I render here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is AppMainComponent was somehow bypassed. Inspired by Mr. Chougrani, I used featured module lazy loading to solve this issue.Changed AppRouting Module is:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
          {path:'',
           component:AppMainComponent,
           children:[
            {path: '',loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)},
            {path: 'Department',loadChildren: () => import('./department/department.module').then(m => m.DepartmentModule)},

           ]
          },
          {path: 'error', component: AppErrorComponent},
          {path: 'access', component: AppAccessdeniedComponent},
          {path: 'notfound', component: AppNotfoundComponent},
          {path: 'login', component: AppLoginComponent},
          {path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound'},
      ])
```

Lazy loaded featured module routing is like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children:[
      {path:'Workbench',component:WorkbenchComponent},
    ]
  }
];
```

More details about lazy loading featured module please see https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules